# Display HTML Page when URL has been added with a parameter in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have an angularjs html page and when edit button is clicked, it will open a new tab that has the edit page, my edit page basically looks like my other html that has initialized ng-controller like this:

```
<div class="container" align="center" ng-controller="prodListCtrl">
```

I have initialized also the path in my route provider like this:

```
.when('/prodListEdit' , {
                    templateUrl : 'angularjs/views/prodListEdit.html',
                    controller : 'prodListCtrl'
                    })
```

On my controller part, I put it inside a function that is called on ng-click of a button.

It looks like this:

```
$scope.editProd = function(id,photo){
        $window.open('/Mirror/#/prodListEdit' +'/'+ id);

        $scope.ProdLinkFormData.link = [ ];
        $scope.MainID = id;

        console.log($scope.MainID);
```

The API is working fine and the response is ok. The only problem is that, the html page is not displaying. But it returns no error. What could possibly be the problem and how can I fix that? I badly needed a help for this

Comment: What is the error, can you also provide the router setup parameters, the stuff that is inside the `app.config`, also there is a `/Mirror` in `$window.open('/Mirror/#/prodListEdit' +'/'+ id);` what is that?

Comment: For me to open the page into a new tab and fetch the values of the id

Comment: You are not having a route for  `/prodListEdit/:id` this may be the problem! can you provide the config if possible, or check to see if this route exists?

Comment: I tried using that but Im not fetching the value of my selected id

Comment: What about this `/Mirror`, what is that? is it some prefix for your website?